# Supremum and infimum being equal at an interval

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Prove / disprove:

If $A,B \subset (0,1)$  not empty, and $\inf B = \sup A =: x$ then $A \cap B = \{x\}$

I first tried to disprove by giving a counter-example such as

$$ A = \{ \frac1n | n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}\}  \\ B = ? \\ \sup A = \frac12$$

But then I wanted to say $B = \{\frac12\}$ this actually satisfies the sentence.

So then I moved to prove this statement, but to no avail, I would appreciate if you could help me!

Assuming $\sup A = x$ then $\forall_{n \in A} ( n < x)$ and $\inf B = x$ then $\forall_{m \in B} ( m > x)$ if $A \cap B = \emptyset $ it is not possible (why?) I really have no clue and I am just talking gibberish..

Comment: What about $A=(1/10, 1/5)$ and$B=(1/5,3/10)$? The intersection is empty. MAybe some condition about $A$ and $B$ is missing?

Comment: @TitoEliatron how? the intersection has 1/5 for both

Comment: NO, $1/5\notin A$ and $1/5\notin B$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron oh oops,  I am so sorry this question now seems trivial... Thanks a lot